# Is it possible for webpack to resolve alias for multiple paths

Tags: javascript, webpack, blueimp

I have next configuration of `webpack`:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            'blueimp-file-upload': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'blueimp-file-upload', 'js', 'jquery.fileupload.js'),
            'blueimp-file-upload-ui': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'blueimp-file-upload', 'js', 'jquery.fileupload-ui.js'),
            'blueimp-file-upload-process': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'blueimp-file-upload', 'js', 'jquery.fileupload-process.js'),
            ...
        }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
    resolve: {
            alias: {
                'blueimp-file-upload': [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'blueimp-file-upload', 'js', 'jquery.fileupload.js'), 
                                        path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'blueimp-file-upload', 'js', 'jquery.fileupload-ui.js'), 
                                        path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'blueimp-file-upload', 'js', 'jquery.fileupload-process.js')],
                ...
            }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: I left it unchanged

Comment: Alright thank you anyway